# getting error in connecting with access database in pdo

Tags: php, sql

I am getting following error while using pdo in php.

My database is in `C:xmapp/htdocs` and php file is in `C:xmapp/htdocs/selftest/`

**My error :**

> Error:SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: -1811 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file '(unknown)'.

**My code:**

```
$database_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\Database11.mdb";
//echo $database_path; die;
try
{
$conn = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$database_path; Uid=$db_username; Pwd=$db_password;");
$conn->setAttribute("PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_Exception");
$stmt=$conn->prepare("insert into user_details(firstname,lastname,filename,sex,qualification) values('$firstname','$lastname','$filename','$sex','$qualification')");
$stmt->exceute();   
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error:".$e->getMessage();
}
$conn=null;
```

Comment: What does `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` output for you and is it expected? Have you tried a forward slash instead of backslash as it appears you are on Windows?

Comment: Not working please give solution

Answer (score 0):

Backslash in string needs to be escaped. try

```
$database_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\\Database11.mdb";
```

or simply use forward slash

```
$database_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Database11.mdb";
```

as forward slash does not have to be escaped but still works perfectly.

Also check if $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] points to the right location.

Comment: I tried both forward and backward slash but not working

Comment: document root is the correct path? try absolute path(if it ha backslash use \\ instead)

Comment: yes it is correct when i echo  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] it displays C:/xampp/htdocs

Comment: ok echo this: "odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$database_path; Uid=$db_username; Pwd=$db_password;"

Comment: It outputs to- odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=C:/xampp/htdocs/Database11.mdb; Uid=; Pwd=

Comment: do you have php_pdo_odbc enabled?

Comment: Please give solution I have enabled php_pdo_odbc but still not work